# CSS script not working

Tags: css

I'm trying to run the html file which includes css tags also. But in the output I can see only html tag's output and not css tag's. I've tried this in all browsers, can I know what is the problem.

Here's my file:

```
<?xml version=”1.0” encoding=”UTF-16”?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC “-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN”
“http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd”>
<html xmlns=”http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml” xml:lang=”en”>
<head>
<title>Bohemia</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style=”text-align:center”>
<h1>Bohemia</h1>
<h2>by Dorothy Parker</h2>
</div>
<p style=”text-align:left”>
Authors and actors and artists and such<br />
Never know nothing, and never know much.<br />
Sculptors and singers and those of their kidney<br />
Tell their affairs from Seattle to Sydney.
</p>
<p style=”text-align:center”>
Playwrights and poets and such horses’ necks<br />
Diarists, critics, and similar roe<br />
Never say nothing, and never say no.
</p>
<p style=”text-align:right”>
People Who Do Things exceed my endurance;<br />
God, for a man that solicits insurance!
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here(output) css alignment tags are not working.

Answer (score 0):

The quotes you're using are wrong. Try using ' or " instead:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Bohemia</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div style=”text-align:center”>
    <h1>Bohemia</h1>
    <h2>by Dorothy Parker</h2>
    </div>
    <p style='text-align:left'>
    Authors and actors and artists and such
    Never know nothing, and never know much.
    Sculptors and singers and those of their kidney
    Tell their affairs from Seattle to Sydney.
    </p>
    <p style='text-align:center'>
    Playwrights and poets and such horses’ necks
    Diarists, critics, and similar roe
    Never say nothing, and never say no.
    </p>
    <p style='text-align:right'>
    People Who Do Things exceed my endurance;
    God, for a man that solicits insurance!
    </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `<div style='text-align:center'>` instead of  this

```
<div style=”text-align:center”>,
```

if we use `<div style=”text-align:center”>` like this , 
browser take as `<div style="”text-align:center”"></div>`
 so the style is consider as a string. use ("") or ('') not this one (” )